# Compare two data sets in TABLE A and insert into TABLE B

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario. There are two Tables TABLE-A and TABLE-B. The source is TABLE-A. The destination is TABLE-B. I want to compare the ID with self join. If ID is matching i want to ensure only NOT NULL value is picked. If both records has NULL value then Null value can be considered as ouput.

Below scenario, 
TABLE-A has one duplicate ID i.e 1. In output i will be have one value for that duplicate record and merge data intelligently that NULL VALUES are excluded and if both records are having NULL for any column then NULL will be populated in TABLE-B.

TABLE A

```
ID         NAME       ADDRESS  PHONE   STATUS     PROCESSFLAG
1          YOU        XYZ       NULL    NULL        1
2          PQR        ABC       123     Active      2
1          YOU        NULL      322     NULL        2
```

OUTPUT TABLE B

```
ID         NAME       ADDRESS  PHONE STATUS     PROCESSFLAG
2          PQR        ABC       123    Active      2
1          YOU        XYZ       322      NULL      2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `group by id` and select max() for each column to exclude nulls:

```
insert into tableb(id, name, address, phone, status, processflag)
select id, max(name), max(address), max(phone), max(status), max(processflag)
from tablea
group by id
```

I assume that your problem is the nulls and the non null columns of the duplicates have the same value in different rows or you want the maximum of the 2 values like your sample data.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bec642281e41c9bdb6bc4aa477e3df52).
Results:

```
ID | NAME | ADDRESS | PHONE | STATUS | PROCESSFLAG
-: | :--- | :------ | :---- | :----- | ----------:
 1 | YOU  | XYZ     | 322   | null   |           2
 2 | PQR  | ABC     | 123   | Active |           2
```

Comment: Not max. want to pick only not null values for duplicate records. in case if both the records are null then we can consider it as NULL

Comment: @YounusMohammed This is what the code does, but in case like your sample data for the column PROCESSFLAG, there are 2 different values it picks the max value.