# Populate second Table based on First Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

TableA, TABLE B.

TableA has below records.

```
id  Name    Address phone   RecordType  ProcessStatus
1   ABC      HYD    123      INSERT           4
2   PQR      IND    111      INSERT           4
1   ABC      NULL   6780     UPDATE           3
```

I want to select RECORD_TYPE='UPDATE' type only. If any value of RecordType=UPDATE has NULL value it should compare it with INSERT TYPE record and bring the value instead of populating NULL. I have to populate the Table B in a way that it should reflect as below.

```
id  Name    Address phone   RecordType  ProcessStatus
1   ABC      HYD    6780     UPDATE           3
```

Below is what i have tried.

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.ID,B.ID),
COALESCE(A.ADDRESS,B.ADDRESS),
COALESCE(A.PHONE,B.PHONE),
COALESCE(A.RECORD_TYPE,B.RECORD_TYPE),
COALESCE(A.STATUS,B.STATUS)

 FROM #TEMP A INNER JOIN #TEMP B
ON A.ID=B.ID
WHERE A.RECORD_TYPE='UPDATE'
```

And below is what i am getting.

```
ID  ADDRESS PHONE   RECORD_TYPE STATUS
1   ABC      123    UPDATE         3
1   ABC     NULL    UPDATE         3
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and then ask a question about what you don't understand.

Comment: Added the code which i have tried

Comment: This is the code from the answer of your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57843354/10498828 for a different requirement. What does it have to do with this requirement?

Comment: Above is actual requirement. I was trying to achieve this.

Comment: The code you posted solves the problem of your previous question. Did you try anything for your new requirement?

Comment: What i mentioned in this post is actual requirement. In previous post i have mentioned incorrect details.

Comment: So you know that the code you posted is not your code and does not meet the new requirement. Did you try anything for the new requirement?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check what i have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may give you what you need

```
insert into tableC(id, name, address, phone, recordType, processstatus)
SELECT * FROM (
select i.id, CASE WHEN u.name IS NULL THEN i.name ELSE u.name END name
,CASE WHEN u.address IS NULL THEN i.address ELSE u.address END address
,CASE WHEN u.phone IS NULL THEN i.phone ELSE u.phone END phone
,CASE WHEN u.recordType IS NULL THEN i.recordType ELSE u.recordType END recordType
,CASE WHEN u.processstatus IS NULL THEN i.processstatus ELSE u.processstatus END processstatus
from tableA i
left join tablea u on u.id = i.id and u.RecordType = 'UPDATE'
where i.RecordType = 'INSERT' 

union

SELECT u.id,u.name,u.address,u.phone,u.RecordType, u.ProcessStatus
FROM tableA u
WHERE NOt EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tableA i where i.id=u.id and i.RecordType = 'INSERT')) f

WHERE f.recordType = 'UPDATE'
order by f.id
```

Comment: This query still gives me INSERT Type records as well.

Comment: I changed it to insert only UPDATE